# How can I add next and previous functionality in the slideshow?

Tags: javascript

I am tried this code, and the slideshow is getting, but want to add some more functionalities once click on the next button the slideshow should stop and the next image should show

```js
    let index = 0
    let address

    let slideShow = () => {
        let cont = document.getElementById("container")
        address = setInterval(() => {
            if(index == image.length){
                index = 0
            }
            cont.innerHTML = null
            let img = document.createElement("img")
            img.src = image[index]
            cont.append(img)
            index++
        }, 1000);
    }

    let stop = () => {
        clearInterval(address)
    }

    let start = () => {
        slideShow()
    }
    slideShow()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach, I extracted some logic from `slideShow` function to another function.

```js
let index = -1;

const slideShow = () => {
    let cont = document.getElementById('container');
    address = setInterval(() => {
        moveSlide(1);
    }, 1000);
};

const moveSlide = (direction) => {
    index = (index + direction) % image.length;
    updateImage(image[index]);
};

const updateImage = (src) => {
    const cont = document.getElementById('container');
    cont.innerHTML = null;
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    cont.append(img);
};
```

Now you can add two buttons for next and previous and use the function moveSlide.

For previous

```js
document.getElementById('prevBtn')
   .addEventListener('click', () => moveSlide(-1));
```

and for next

```js
document.getElementById('nextBtn')
   .addEventListener('click', () => moveSlide(1));
```